# Can not start sshd service: relocation error

Tags: ssh, kerberos, rpm, package-management, mitkerberos

After updating openssh version from 5.3 to 7.9 I am having problems when I try to start sshd service,

The script that I executed is:

```
rpm -Uvh openssh-latest-7.9p1-1.el6.cgsl7741.x86_64.rpm --nodeps

rpm -Uvh openssh-latest-clients-7.9p1-1.el6.cgsl7741.x86_64.rpm --nodeps

rpm -Uvh openssh-latest-server-7.9p1-1.el6.cgsl7741.x86_64.rpm --nodeps
```

the following error appears:

```
Starting sshd: /usr/local/openssh/sbin/sshd: relocation error: 
/usr/local/openssh/sbin/sshd: symbol krb5_cc_support_switch, 
version krb5_3_MIT not defined in file libkrb5.so.3 with link time reference

[FAILED]
```

I tried some suggestions I found on the web without success.

Comment: Where did you get these RPMs? Why did you override dependency checking?

Comment: I just found that on internet.  do you know what could be the problem?

Comment: The problem is that you installed the packages without their dependencies.

Comment: I have executed the same commands in other servers without problems.  Where can I find those dependencies? sorry but I am new in Linux.

Comment: Again, what did you do to get the system into this state?

Comment: So a couple of things: 1. You should not be installing random .RPM packages from arbitrary locations on the Internet. That is how it looks to us based on how you have posed your question. 2. On a modern *NIX operating system, you should probably be using the official package-management system, not the `rpm` command, unless you specifically need to do something only RPM can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution. I installed again some dependencies of krb5

```
#  rpm -qa|grep krb5
krb5-devel-1.10.3-33.el6.x86_64
krb5-libs-1.10.3-33.el6.x86_64
krb5-pkinit-openssl-1.10.3-33.el6.x86_64
krb5-appl-clients-1.0.1-6.el6.x86_64
krb5-server-1.10.3-33.el6.x86_64
krb5-workstation-1.10.3-33.el6.x86_64
krb5-server-ldap-1.10.3-33.el6.x86_64
```

and then start sshd service

```
# service sshd restart
Stopping sshd:                                             [  OK  ]
Starting sshd:                                             [  OK  ]
```

I hope this can help somebody in the future.